# How to run Teams Audio Calling Bot (PSI bot)

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to create a teams calling bot, and following this document - [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-calling-and-meeting) but when I am trying to run the PowerShell command getting these types of error
[error that I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR3jK.png)

when I am trying to run the code for the teams calling bot implemented in c# from this github repo [here] Getting these types of error
[error that I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr1px.png)
[error that I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUda8.png)

when following this document for the teams calling bot implemented in c# from this github repo [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/microsoft-teams-samples/officedev-microsoft-teams-samples-bot-calling-meeting-csharp) getting this type of errors -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpSMY.png)

My main aim is to run a teams calling bot having
[functionality that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD9m7.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need execuite any powershell commands, just go through the steps in readme file of this [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-all-cards/csharp)